# Unable to find conversation: skills skilldialog sample

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I cloned the botbuilder-samples from GitHub and tried to run the 81.skills-skilldialog sample.  When my dialogRootBot sends a skill activity to the dialogSkillBot, the dialogSkillBot is unable to respond back.  Here is the error it is returning

```
[onTurnError] Exception caught in sendEoCToParent: Error: /api/messages/v3/conversations/d24ed016-6872-4a57-bd99-c93aa061e32c-8b8cc16a-597d-4bae-a4e0-b992af4d9b38-a:11XpYDC7setK3n4POxpFnsvU_143zXeMzsTqFuspVzDeE5fmF02wN0tqvWdvSjd89cdG9f7RWm-Gr76RV8z-Ny3j4NM24noCOmWV7zUxqqBbyc6SILj8Fkz0iW2l2HYHN-msteams-skillconvo/activities/1589352227371 does not exist
```

Any ideas why this is happening?  What am I missing?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was something with the NPM package I was using.  After updating to version ~4.9.0, my problem went away.